# Searching the youTube V3 API via channel name not username?

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

Youtube allows a username and channel name. They can be different from each other. The youtube API allows me to search via username but I can't see where or how to search by channel name. It is the channel name that is displayed under the videos. 
 Anyone shed some light onto how I can search via channel name/title and **not** username? 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the channel search API didn't return a result I call the search API

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=channel&maxResults=1&q=(<# potential channel name #>)

So it runs a standard search for entered value "potential channel name". Google docs say the first returned result will be a channel so we only need 1 result which is why we set maxResults=1.

If that returns nothing then I assume channel does not exists and display error to user

Comment: Is there any sense in the sequences of characters `(<#` and `#>)`?

Comment: When you copy paste into Xcode <# .... #> is replaced with a placeholder. It's just a syntax trick. Anyone copy pasting should enter a potential channel name it's its place.

Comment: I think that search uses 100 units of quota cost. do you know a cheaper method?

Answer (score 2):

This works with me, just change the key with your api-key

url1="*[https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=channel&maxResults=15&q=Inna&key=[YOUR-API-KEY]*"

r = requests.get((url1))

print(r.content)

It returns all channels with names that contain the word Inna
Hope this can help you

Comment: You probably shouldn’t share an api key on this forum